# Error message in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I can build and run the app in the emulator but when I try and generate signed apk the following happens.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Invalid main APK outputs : BuildOutput{apkInfo={type=MAIN, versionCode=0, filters=[]}, path=C:\Users\datan\StudioProjects\gamex\app\release\app-release.apk, properties=},BuildOutput{apkInfo={type=MAIN, versionCode=0, filters=[]}, path=C:\Users\datan\StudioProjects\gamex\app\release\space-release.apk, properties=}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try below one

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        lintOptions {
            disable 'MissingTranslation'
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`config` in `build.gradle`:

```
lintOptions {
      checkReleaseBuilds false
       abortOnError false
    }
```